# Regarding Access Specifier

Tags: c

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h> 

main()
{
  printf(" %d %f ",4.0,4.0);
  getch();
}
```

I am getting output as `0` `4.000000`
I want to know why `4.0` become `zero` as the integer specifier is used ?
Why it is not truncated to `4`?

Comment: Please search for some introductory C tutorial/book from this century.

Comment: because binary representation of 4.0 is `0x40100000_00000000`, %d takes last 4 bytes from it, ie `0x00000000`

Comment: Enable proper warnings and treat them as errors: g++: `warning: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘main’ with no type [-Wpedantic]` and `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]`

Comment: I don't see anything strange about this question. It is pretty usual to think that way. OP expects `int x = 4.5` to be truncated to `4`. The same logic can be applied here, unfortunately wrong.

Comment: Thanks to all for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convince your self try the following. There are few things to notice - implicit conversion of float to int, parameter access by printf() from stack, which determines the memory locations and size to obtain the value stored based on the format specifier.

```
printf(" %d %f ", (int)4.0, 4.0);
printf(" %d %f ", (float)4, 4.0);
printf(" %d %f ", (float)0, 4.0);
```

Comment: What if if I don't want to do explicit type casting? Why implicit conversion hasn't been encountered?

Comment: If you don't explicitly type cast, then compiler would consider pushing the floating point data using the number of bytes needed (as it doesn't have a clue on how the printf function works internally i.e., how many bytes it needs to read, which is determined by the format specifier) represent such a value just like Leshane and Scott mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

You basically *lied* to `printf`, passing it a floating-point value where you promised in an integer one; @Lashane explained how it might have come up with 0 (a binary representation of 4.0 being `0x40100000_00000000`, and %d takes the last 4 bytes which are all 0).  However, because this is undefined behavior, one might get a different result in different circumstances.

Comment: Since comments may vanish you should probably add this to your answer (and note that it's undefined behaviour, thus must be avoided). (Just saying, didn't downvote)

Comment: Yeah it would be the probable reason